# Count cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image] I have a specific and difficult task that I will explain further. I won't use VBAExcel since this is not the case:

- I have **5** **columns** in a specific **row** like this: 50  100    blank  blank   blank - parameter A.
- In the **same row** I have other **5** **columns** like this: 50 blank   100    blank   100 - parameter B

Those numbers correspond to marks in different evaluations. In the first set there are 2 numbers and in the second 3 numbers. But the total number of evaluations are 4. How can I count them?
Each evaluation contains "A" and "B" or only one of them because the total is 100. Only the 4th evaluation doesn't exist. I want to count the total number of evaluations for every situation.

- 1st test: A  - 50 B = 50;
- 2st test: A  - 100 B = blank;
- 3st test: A  - blank  B = 100;
- 4st test: A  - blank B =blank; - this test didn't happen.
- 5st test: A  - blank B = 100;

## tests = 5

Comment: what do you mean `5 columns in a specific row?` and `In the same row I have other 5 columns`? :))

Comment: Please show a screenshot of some of the data - it's difficult to understand from your description (I can't understand why there are five numbers but only four evaluations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this is the best way but here are the steps I take:

- First, i used offset to `split range` contains number into 2 parallel arrays with different color (yellow and blue)
- Next, combining them together to identify the vacant positions simultaneously. Evaluating these `sum of pairs> 0` ->> returns the result = 1, and the
- Finally, calculate the number of pairs.

.

```
D8=SUMPRODUCT(--((OFFSET(A6:J6,,,1,5)+OFFSET(A6:J6,,5,1,5))>0))
```

[image]

Hope it works!

Comment: I have to skip to cells in the middle between the 2 parameters. How can I do that?.

Comment: can you explain more: `between the 2 parameters`?

Comment: he two parameters are not adjacent. A is between A6:E6 for example and parameter B is between H6:L6. F6 and G6 have other values and don't matter.

Comment: @PedroR.: you can try: `=SUMPRODUCT(--((A6:E6+H6:L6)>0))`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your requirement you can use a helper row with some random indexes.
Thus, even the 4th test where the result is empty will be counted and your number of evaluations will be 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following formula.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--((A6:E6+F6:J6)>0))`

Adjust the ranges to suit actual columns